# URL with brackets compared to full URL

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino

Why would #1 work, but not #2 or 3 when used in a $$Return field if database is being accessed using IE11?  The field is hidden.

1. [db_path/db_filename/Page?OpenPage]
2. http://server_dns/db_path/db_filename/Page?OpenPage
3. server_dns/db_path/db_filename/Page?OpenPage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A URL in brackets (e.g., [db_path/db_filename/Page?OpenPage]) is *interpreted by the Domino server* as a command to send an HTTP 30x REDIRECT response (probably a 303, but I'm not sure) to the browser. Upon receipt of this response, the browser interprets it as an instruction to retrieve the specified URL. That's simply a matter of compliance with standards, so all browsers will do it.

The other choices you list are not treated as anything special by the Domino server. They are simply sent as ordinary content in a 200 OK response to the browser's POST request. No standards apply to this, so a browser may or may not choose to recognize that the response text looks like a URL and may or may not choose to do something with it - e.g., follow the link. Based on your question, it appears that IE11 does not do anything with it. It doesn't follow the URL. Frankly, I had no idea that any browser would do actually follow a URL if it is received as the sole content with a 200 OK response.